# Map in Xamarin ListView

Tags: google-maps, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, lag

I have a ListView in my Xamarin Android app where I have over 100 list items. Each item has a Google Maps  component showing a map of an area. I have realized that this causes the vertical scrolling of the ListView to lag (due to each  component is pretty computational heavy I suppose). Each  area is about Width x 128 pixels.

I am now thinking of how I can show the map of the area and still have good performance in the scrolling. One idea is to generate a small image of each area and bind it to the ListView item instead. However, as far as I understand, it is not technically possible to generate images from the Google Maps API (map + marker).

How would you recommended to solve this? Do you think I have some other bottleneck rather than the 100  instances? In my tests its pretty obvious it started to lag when I added the  component. However, the  component is hidden (IsVisible="False") unless you expand the List Item, but still its "there" and the lag persist. Is it normal to have so many  components first of all?

My map is part of a Grid and looks like this:

```
<Frame Grid.Row="4" x:Name="expandArea" BackgroundColor="Transparent" IsVisible="False" Padding="0" Margin="0" HasShadow="True">
  <maps:Map x:Name="userMap" MinimumHeightRequest="128" HeightRequest="128" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</Frame>
```

Comment: Will location of the map be changed dynamically? If these locations are static, 100 sceenshots of maps are acceptable, if they are dynamic, you can show the location by text in the listview, then click the item of listview, navigate to the subview to show the map.

Comment: Try pagination, first load only 10 items, then if the scroll reached end drag, then try to add another 10 in the list. Refer https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/140750/pagination-on-scrolling-of-listview-in-xamarin-android

Comment: Yes, I tried add 10 items, it could be scrolled, but I add over 50 items, application will crash.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @LeonLu-MSFT how can I generate/create the screenshots from Google Maps API? (including the marker)

Comment: You can  create a listview with postion name, then click the item, navigate the details page(contains map and pins), open the details page, you can use dependence service to take a sceenshot programmatically like this thread. https://xamarinhelp.com/taking-a-screenshot-in-xamarin-forms/